# Button click Event in user control not firing because of WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: c#, user-controls

We had used a User Control Image button click to generate a Excel and I am using this user control in my aspx page by registering it

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/PaginationControl.ascx" TagName="ucPagination" TagPrefix="UC" %>
```

I am using this user control in many pages in some pages its working the HTML code for the button generated during runtime for the working pages is

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$pagination1$ExcelBtn" id="MainContent_pagination1_ExcelBtn" 
title="Export To Excel" class="excel-ico" border="0" src="Images/excel.jpg" 
onclick="CallClickEventExcel();" 
style="height:16px;">
```

and the coding in aspx page is

```
<UC:ucPagination ID="pagination1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

but in one of the page where I had used the same User Control the HTML code generated during runtime is

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$pagination1$ExcelBtn" 
id="MainContent_pagination1_ExcelBtn" title="Export To Excel" 
class="excel-ico" border="0" src="Images/excel.jpg" 
onclick="CallClickEventExcel();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$pagination1$ExcelBtn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
style="height:16px;">
```

and the coding in aspx page is

```
<UC:ucPagination ID="pagination1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

as you can see **`WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$pagination1$ExcelBtn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))`** extra added in the code generated during runtime.

I had stuck with this issue for hours kindly anyone give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used the below code to solve the error

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".Validators").Float();
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pagination1_ExcelBtn").onclick = function () { CallClickEventExcel(); };
            document.getElementById("MainContent_pagination2_ExcelBtn").onclick = function () { CallClickEventExcel(); };
        });
```